# loosing session after inactivity in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, screensaver, session

I recently updated to 17.10 and i notice that after a long period of inactivity (when the screen goes blank), when i tried to login i can enter the desktop environment, almost instantly it disappears again and it probes me to login again. This time after the login, all my work is lost and it's like i am in a total new session. It's the second time it happens.Even Chrome closes and looses all the tab i had opened when i left my computer! Any help please i'm fearing now leaving any work incomplete.

Comment: Please report bug to [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/) with `apport-bug` and write complete steps to reproduce.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same.  If you file a bug, please update your comment with the link. Thanks.

Comment: Is this your issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1723772

Comment: i updated the kernel too to 4.14-rc6 but network interface stopped working . Tried reinstall network manager , put ipv4 details manually  (because i read about a dns bug) but nothing. At that point after some little tries i reinstall  4.13.0-16-generic x86_64 . If problem appears again i tried to filled a bug report. Thanx for your answers guys.

Comment: I've been suffering from the same issue since I switched back from Fedora a few months ago.  Should I ditch it (again) and go with something else?  Perhaps Arch this time...